# How can I fit my keras model with my own data generated at runtime

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to do a Generative Adversarial Network, but I can't fit the generator model. I use Sequential() model with only Dense layers, first with an input_shape=(1,) and last with imgsize[0] * imgsize[1] * 3 output space. imgsize = (28, 28) so output space have 2352 units.

I need to fit with "real cost" and "previous image" but when I try to fit with output of previous predict an error appear.

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected GenDense5 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2352,)

```py
generator = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name="GenDenseIn"),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="GenDense2"),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="GenDense3"),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="GenDense4"),
    keras.layers.Dense(imgsize[0] * imgsize[1] * 3, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name="GenDense5")
])

generator.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

gen = generator.predict(np.array([1])) # 1 to find the best
img = gen.reshape((1, imgsize[0], imgsize[1], 3))

res = discriminator.predict(img) # Dicriminator evaluate real or fake value
cost = res[0][0] # Real value

model.fit(np.array([cost]), np.array(gen), epochs=100) #ERROR!
```

Comment: Can you try creating a variable to hold imgsize[0] * imgsize[1] * 3 value and then put that variable in the final dense layer?

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator model have to output 2352, but those numbers are a collective value (an image) but the model is compiled with a sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss function, that is a function for categorical classification like my discriminator. The answer is use mean_squared_error loss function.

```py
generator.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```